# NSImage loading a portion of image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsimage

The requirement is like this, 
I would get a single large PNG Images for a button, this single image will contain images for hOver, button clicked , mouse exit that need to be displayed, 
Single PNG File size would be 1024 X 28, so each image have size about 256 X 28, 
I am googling the best possible approach but couldn't make out how to achieve this,

I have following approach in mind,

```m
NSImage *pBtnImage[MAX_BUTTON_IMAGES]
for ( i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
pBtnImage[i] = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:??????]; 
}
```

I want to know what should i give in the NSData parameter,

Is it possible to load a Single Image and clipped image accordingly as and when it needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're directly subverting the clever OS that Apple has put together to hide and show UIViews in order to... save from having to slice up the image? Keep track of 3 images instead of 1? What's the advantage that makes it worth countering what the OS is designed to do well?

Comment: Hi Matthew,another use case is like this, i need to set the Image against each menu item, i would have a large PNG of say 128X28, i have to extract a single image of 28 X 28 and assign that perticular NSImage to the Menu item , i hope i am able to explain you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple Cocoa-supported way to read only a sub-rectangle of the image from its *data*. It's a simple matter, however, to read the whole image in and only use a select rectangle of the image when compositing. Thing is, with all the available API, you might be better off just to use the standard +[NSImage imageNamed:] method to read the images in individually and let the OS handle caching.

What *actual, measured performance problem* are you trying to solve? Does one really exist, or is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: HI, We are porting a windows application on the MAC, to maintain consistency, we would like to use existing image set which is in Above form, i.e. there would be a large single image , use a portion/subrecetangle to create NSImage and assign to button, menu ite etc... , now how can i achieve the same in COCOA

Comment: 1) It's "Mac" and "Cocoa". They're not acronyms. 2) I've already answered that question: load the whole image and use subrects of the image to create the individual images in memory.

Comment: about loading a complete image, i understood, but my question is, how can i created Another NSImage point using subrect of existing image, why because, if i have NSImage of sub-rect i can easily assign to all controls like button, menu, NSImageview etc.. , i suppose you are telling use drawRect and draw a subrect of NSImage but if i use this, then i have to add lot of code for each controls,

Comment: Create a new NSImage with the size of the subrect, lock focus on it, draw the sub rect of the source image into the new, locked image using -drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction: ("fromRect:" should be the subrect of the source; the first rect argument will be a rect of the same size as the subrect, with a 0,0 origin), then unlock focus from the new image. Done. Because of all that's involved in this, it might *still* be more efficient just to load individual images...

Comment: Thanks Joshua, i will try the same